# trying to connect to smtp server using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, tcp, smtp, nodemailer

Unable to connect to the SMTP server. Is there a better way to connect and check the validity of the SMTP server from the domain?

```js
var net = require('net');
const dns = require('dns')
const SMTPConnection = require("nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection");

dns.resolveMx('gmail.com', function(err, addresses){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  // just taking the first mail server
  h = addresses[0].exchange;
  options = {
    host:h,
    port:25,
    connectionTimeout: 3000
  };

  let connection = new SMTPConnection(options);
  connection.connect(()=>{console.log('connected')});
  connection.on('error', (err)=>{console.log(err)})
  connection.on('end', ()=>{console.log('end')})
})
```

**Error**

```js
{ Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 142.250.11.26:25
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '142.250.11.26',
  port: 25,
  command: 'CONN' }
end
```

I get the same error when I try with `new net.Socket([options])` from the `net` module

Comment: I'm not sure what *"better way"* you expect. If the server is not reachable even by socket you cannot reach it. The problem is likely that the access to this server (mx.google.com) is somehow blocked from your system maybe by some local firewall which means every method to access the server directly from this specific system will fail, no matter which method you use.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, but the telnet command on port 25 works. Not sure how.

Comment: *"...the telnet command on port 25 works."* - from the exact same environment, i.e. same system/VPS/container, same user, ... ?

Comment: from the same VPS

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the telnet command for comparison? Also, same VPS but also same user?